# what is the best way to create a state of array or state of array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, setstate

I am having websocket connection between client and server.

Client want to display list of ID's and its progressValue.

Server on other end is sending always array of obj with length 1 for example

```
[{"processid": "1","progressVal" : 10%}]
[{"processid": "2","progressVal" : 5%}]
[{"processid": "1","progressVal" : 25%}]
[{"processid": "3","progressVal" : 1%}]
[{"processid": "2","progressVal" : 12%}]
like that it keeps sending processid and its progressVal
```

now on server side its not having any state. it just sends data to client then and there.

On client side, client want to listen to the message sent by server, and create an array to store progressid and progressVal so that it can loop through it to display it in GUI.

logic:

1. want to create an single array with list of processid and progressVal
2. check if processid already exists in the created list,
   if yes, then check if progressVal is same and if not then update the progressVal
   if no, then add the processid and progressVal in to this array.

expected results

```
  dataFromServer = [{"processid": "1","progressVal" : 10%}]
  then proList = [{"processid": "1","progressVal" : 10%}]
  dataFromServer = [{"processid": "2","progressVal" : 5%}]
  then proList = [{"processid": "1","progressVal" : 10%},{"processid": "2","progressVal" : 5%} ]
  dataFromServer = [{"processid": "1","progressVal" : 25%}]
  then proList = [{"processid": "1","progressVal" : 25%},{"processid": "2","progressVal" : 5%} ]
  dataFromServer = [{"processid": "3","progressVal" : 1%}]
  then proList = [{"processid": "1","progressVal" : 25%},{"processid": "2","progressVal" : 5%}, {"processid": "3","progressVal" : 1%} ]
  dataFromServer = [{"processid": "2","progressVal" : 12%}]
  then proList = [{"processid": "1","progressVal" : 25%},{"processid": "2","progressVal" : 12%}, {"processid": "3","progressVal" : 1%} ]
```

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      dataFromServer : ""
    }
  }
 componentDidMount(){
     client.onmessage = (message) => {
      this.setState({dataFromServer: JSON.parse(message.data)});
    };
  }
  render() {
    if(!this.state.dataFromServer){
      return "loading"
    }
    else if(this.state.dataFromServer && this.state.dataFromServer.length >0){
      return(
        <div>
        <processList dataFromServer={this.state.dataFromServer}/>
      </div>
      );
    }
  }
}
export default App;
```

```
class processList extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {  
      proList : [{
      id: "",
      progVal: parseInt("0%")
}]   // i want to set here initial values for id and progVal
    }
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    if(this.props.dataFromServer){
      this.props.dataFromServer.map(d => {
        let arr = [];
        let objToPush = {id: element.id, progVal: element.progVal};
        arr.push(objToPush);
        this.setState ({
          proList: arr
        });
      });
    }
  }
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState){     //want to push into array if processId is new, and want to update the progVal if processId already exists in array
    this.props.dataFromServer.map(d => {

      }
      else if(prevState.proList.id == d.id){
                                                    //not sure how to do logic here.
      } 
    })
  }
    render(){
    return(
      this.state.proList.map(data => {              
          return(
            <div>
                <p>{data.id}</p>
                <p>{data.progVal}</p>
            </div>
            );
      })
    );
};
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code if you want to set update the proList (i.e., array of objects, which is my suggested approach for this).

1. You will map through the newly received data
2. Through the `proList` array state variable, you will see if any element has the same `id` as the element under consideration (`d`)
3. If you find an element through step 2, its index will be greater than -1 (`find()` method returns -1 if no match is found, or if the element is found gives the proper index), check if the `progVal` of the newly received data object under consideration (`d`) is same as the old one. If not, update it.
4. If you don't find an element through step 2, push the newfound object to the array, then set`proList` to the array and thus update it.

.

```
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    let arr = [...this.state.proList]; // side-note: do this, because you don't want to mutate the original array like you were doing in your code

    this.props.dataFromServer.forEach((d) => {
      let index = prevState.proList.findIndex((el) => el.id === d.id); // where is uid coming from? all the other places you've written 'id' and not 'uid'

      let objectToPush = { id: d.id, progVal: d.progVal };
      if (index > -1) {
        // i.e, if some occurence is found,
        if (arr[index].progVal !== d.progVal) {
          arr[index] = objectToPush; // insert this object at the index of the old object
          this.setState({
            proList: arr
          });
        }
      } else {
        arr.push(objectToPush); // append to the array, since it's a new id
        this.setState({
          proList: arr
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: sure will give it a try. but what about in componentdidmount -> do you think its wrong way to push data to array state.

Comment: sorry its "id" not "uid"

Comment: Yes, because that will be mutating the array state (since `push( )` alters the original array) , and it won't trigger a re-render (not that you wanted it to re-render, but anyway). It's considered a bad practice in react-osphere. [Official documentation advises to consider states as immutable](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#state). In cases where the state variable is something like an array or an object, it's always better to make a duplicate, operate on it, and then update the state variable.

Comment: so i have a question: as per your code,you recommend to use proList and not dataList right. but what about setting intial value in proList. for example i want initial value of id and progVal to be empty for example. also i have updated the code for componentdidmount.

Comment: i tried to use the code, but i get this error: Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I follow, do you want to initialise your `proList` state array with blank values? If yes, what's the fun of it? You can initialise it as an empty array, but doing what you're doing in your code, you are essentially creating an element having no data like `{id: '', progVal: 0}`, this will result in that element staying there as it will pass through the `find()` logic.

Edit: I'm looking into replicating your code atm, will fix this issue.

Comment: so this is the scenario: initial values of "processid" and progVal i want to set in constructor (you can see in code) now i want to update the list with incoming values from server. for example, server 1st send processid= 1 and its progVal = 5. now i create proList with id = 1 and progVal = 5, next server sends processid = 2 and progVal = 10, now i update the proList = [ {id: 1,progVal:5},{id:2,progVal:10}]. now server sends processid = 1 and progVal = 25. then my proList = [{id:1, progVal: 25},{id:2,progVal: 10}] something like this.

Comment: i have added a section for expected results. may be you get what i am trying to do

Comment: Can you replace your code with [my sandbox code](https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-resonance-iicbp?file=/src/App.js) to see if it works? I changed the data flow and data structures, so that the storage and rendering becomes convenient to understand.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234247/discussion-between-areeb-khan-and-user28).